# Historical Wave and Current data

Tags: data-request, weather, historical

I am looking for an archive with historical predictions as well as actual measured currents, wind and waves for the baltic sea.

http://forecast.io covers other data points that I need, but wave and currents are missing.

OAA National Oceangraphic Data Center seems to have the data I need, but not for the Baltics :-/ [0].

I would appreciate any hint for data archives. Thanks.

[0] http://opendap.co-ops.nos.noaa.gov/ioos-dif-sos/SOS?service=SOS&request=GetObservation&version=1.0.0&observedProperty=currents&offering=urn:ioos:network:NOAA.NOS.CO-OPS:All&procedure=urn:ioos:network:NOAA.NOS.CO-OPS:CurrentsActive&featureOfInterest=BBOX:9,54,12,57&responseFormat=text%2Fcsv